# How to reset the rotation time after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, settimeout

Now I'm developing an news slider and it works properly without any problem

Slider has 5 icons to jump to a certain new, here the problem appears.

the rotation time is 4 sec and when i click to the icon it jumps to the new but the time not start from the beginning , it complete the remaining time of the 4 sec and rotate to the next

i want it to start from the beginning, below the code of rotating

```
time_id = setTimeout(Rotate, 4000);

function Rotate() {

    var class_name = $('.list_items li').eq(0).attr('class');

    var class_name_2 = $('li.small_to_large').removeClass('small_to_large').attr('class');  
    $('.' + class_name_2).css({display: 'block'});

    $('.' + class_name).before($('.' + class_name_2));

    $('.' + class_name).addClass('small_to_large');
    $('.' + class_name).css({display:'none'});

    $('div.large-12').before($('.' + class_name));

    $('.one-slide img').attr('src',$('li.small_to_large img').attr('src'));
    $('.one-slide h1').html($('.small_to_large h1').html());
    $('.one-slide p.small_desc').html($('.small_to_large p.small_desc').html());
    $('.one-slide p.disc').html($('.small_to_large p.disc').html());

    seeker();
    time_id = setTimeout(Rotate_1, 4000);
}
function Rotate_1() {

    var class_name = $('.list_items li').eq(0).next().attr('class');

    var class_name_2 = $('li.small_to_large').removeClass('small_to_large').attr('class');  
    $('.' + class_name_2).css({display: 'block'});

    $('.' + class_name).before($('.' + class_name_2));

    $('.' + class_name).addClass('small_to_large');
    $('.' + class_name).css({display:'none'});

    $('div.large-12').before($('.' + class_name));

    $('.one-slide img').attr('src',$('li.small_to_large img').attr('src'));
    $('.one-slide h1').html($('.small_to_large h1').html());
    $('.one-slide p.small_desc').html($('.small_to_large p.small_desc').html());
    $('.one-slide p.disc').html($('.small_to_large p.disc').html());

    seeker();
    time_id = setTimeout(Rotate_2, 4000);
}
function Rotate_2() {

    var class_name = $('.list_items li').eq(0).next().next().attr('class');

    var class_name_2 = $('li.small_to_large').removeClass('small_to_large').attr('class');  
    $('.' + class_name_2).css({display: 'block'});

    $('.' + class_name).before($('.' + class_name_2));

    $('.' + class_name).addClass('small_to_large');
    $('.' + class_name).css({display:'none'});

    $('div.large-12').before($('.' + class_name));

    $('.one-slide img').attr('src',$('li.small_to_large img').attr('src'));
    $('.one-slide h1').html($('.small_to_large h1').html());
    $('.one-slide p.small_desc').html($('.small_to_large p.small_desc').html());
    $('.one-slide p.disc').html($('.small_to_large p.disc').html());

    seeker();
    time_id = setTimeout(Rotate_3, 4000);
}
function Rotate_3() {

    var class_name = $('.list_items li').eq(0).next().next().next().attr('class');

    var class_name_2 = $('li.small_to_large').removeClass('small_to_large').attr('class');  
    $('.' + class_name_2).css({display: 'block'});

    $('.' + class_name).before($('.' + class_name_2));

    $('.' + class_name).addClass('small_to_large');
    $('.' + class_name).css({display:'none'});

    $('div.large-12').before($('.' + class_name));

    $('.one-slide img').attr('src',$('li.small_to_large img').attr('src'));
    $('.one-slide h1').html($('.small_to_large h1').html());
    $('.one-slide p.small_desc').html($('.small_to_large p.small_desc').html());
    $('.one-slide p.disc').html($('.small_to_large p.disc').html());

    seeker();
    time_id = setTimeout(Rotate, 4000);
}

function seeker(){
    $('.one-slide .seeker i').animate({width: '100%'},4000, function() {
        $('.one-slide .seeker i').css({width: 0});
    });
}
```

the code of icon clicking

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_items li',  function(){

    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');

    var class_name_2 = $('li.small_to_large').removeClass('small_to_large').attr('class');  
    $('.' + class_name_2).css({display: 'block'});

    $('.' + class_name).before($('.' + class_name_2));

    $('.' + class_name).addClass('small_to_large');
    $('.' + class_name).css({display:'none'});

    $('div.large-12').before($('.' + class_name));


    $('.one-slide img').attr('src',$('li.small_to_large img').attr('src'));
    $('.one-slide h1').html($('.small_to_large h1').html());
    $('.one-slide p.small_desc').html($('.small_to_large p.small_desc').html());
    $('.one-slide p.disc').html($('.small_to_large p.disc').html());

    $('.one-slide .seeker i').css({width: 0});
    seeker();

});
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine :)

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_items li',  function(){

    clearTimeout(time_id);
    $('.one-slide .seeker i').stop( true, true );
    seeker();
    time_id = setTimeout(Rotate, 4000);

    ................................
    ................................

});
```

thanks you **Trevor**

Answer (score 0):

`clearTimeout()` should do it for you. e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_items li',  function(){
 clearTimeout(time_id);  // should clear it for you
 .....
 seeker();
 time_id = setTimeout(Rotate, 4000); // Now you can start it up again on the appropriate rotate. 
});
```

**Update**

Now you just need to come up with a way to call the appropriate rotate function depending on what image you are on.

Comment: thank you Trevor, the rotation functions are not the same, as the first one change the large new with the first small one, and the second function change with the second small one

Comment: @MohamedAref Okay I updated my answer removing the last part.  Did that help you?  You just need to keep track of which picture you are on when you click and then call the appropriate rotate function from there.